# clinical trial for getting history for particular NCT ID

Tags: python, api, bioinformatics, medical

I need a complete history for particular clinical trial NCT ID from site: https://clinicaltrials.gov/

Consider `NCT id :NCT03245346`

From [link](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03245346?recrs=ab&cond=Cancer%20of%20Pancreas&draw=2&rank=4) I am checking for `History of Changes` which is giving me all history for that `NCT ID` in [new page](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/archive/NCT03245346).

I can get this using HTML parser:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/archive/NCT03245346'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

tab = soup.find("table", {"class":"ct-data_table tr-data_table tr-tableStyle"})
print(tab)
```

**But to avoid on HTML page format, I would like to know, is there any API for getting a complete history for particular NCT ID?**

Comment: did you see https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/gui

Comment: Yes, I have checked. But no luck

Comment: If you find the solution then please share the info as I'm currently struggling with same problem. If I'll find a way I'll post it here as well

Comment: @puchal: I did not find the solution.

Comment: @puchal: Check answer by c0rias. This worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately I still need some other source of historical data as this view doesn't contain all information as xml output does. (Some fields are missing)

Comment: @puchal Did you get any better solution?

Comment: @puchal : from where I can take those XMLs?

Comment: No unfortunately there is no better way for retrieving historical information rather than scraping web pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get the table, you can try pandas `read_html()` function:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/archive/NCT03245346"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

df.head()

    0                               1
0   ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier:  NCT03245346
1   Study Title:                    Effects of Epidural Anesthesia and Analgesia o...
2   First Submitted:                August 2, 2017
3   Last Update Posted:             April 24, 2018
```

This also works for the more "detailed" overview when you click on *Continue to the history of changes for this study on the ClinicalTrials.gov Archive Site*:

```py
url_detail = "https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/history/NCT03245346"

df = pd.read_html(url_detail)[0]
```

Yet if you are looking for something else, maybe we can figure this one out, too.

Comment: you answer is better than HTML parsing solution. Atleast I don't have to depend on HTML page but only on 0th table. So to reduce that dependencies too, please let me know if you know any API to get the same